# Css on html table with 2 columns. (left column contains image, right one contains data about image)

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

The idea is that i want a table with 2 columns. The left column will contain an image and the right one will have 6 rows which will display data about the image.

```
________________________________
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|     image     |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|_______________|_______________|
```

This example displays it as i want it
index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

 <table style="width:50%" height = "350" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="6" ><img src="1466570127.jpg" alt=""></img></th>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>555 77 855</td></tr>
  <tr><td>555 77 856</td></tr>
  <tr><td>555 77 857</td></tr>
  <tr><td>555 77 858</td></tr>
  <tr><td>555 77 859</td></tr>
 </table>

</body>          
</html>
```

But when i tried to use this code in my project for some reason it gets messed up and looks exactly like this:

```
________________________________
|               |               |
|               |               |
|     image     |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|               |_______________|
|_______________|_______________|
```

I belive the problem has to be in my css file but i still can't find it.
Any hint will be helpfull and thank you in advance for your time.
I will give you my code in case it helps:
html:

```
<?php 
include_once("config.php"); //include the config
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title> Photography Site </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Mainbody.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/800px.css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Menu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/SideBar.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Container">    
        <?php include 'menu.php';?>
        <?php include 'display_photos.php';?>
          <div id="MainBody">

             <?php
                //display all photos in database
                $rows = $_SESSION['rows'];
                for ($x = 0; $x < $rows; $x++) {
                    $name = $_SESSION['array'][$x][1];
                    $username = $_SESSION['array'][$x][8];
                    $category = $_SESSION['array'][$x][9];
                    $description = $_SESSION['array'][$x][2];
                    $likes = $_SESSION['array'][$x][7];
                    $path = $_SESSION['array'][$x][3];
                    $res_path = $_SESSION['array'][$x][4];
             ?>
             <table style="width:50%" height = "350" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="6" ><img src="<?php echo $res_path ?>" alt=""></img></th>
                    <td>Name: <?php echo $name; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>User: <?php echo $username; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Category: <?php echo $category; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Description: <?php echo $description; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>path: <?php echo $path; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Likes: <?php echo $likes; ?></td></tr>
            </table>
             <?php } ?> 
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my css file:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* ~~~~~~~~ css reset finished ~~~~~~~~~~*/

body{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-color:#EBF4FA;
}

#Container{
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:11px;
    margin-bottom:21px;
}

#Header {
    height: 140px;
    background: url(logo.png); 
}

#Menu{
    height:60px;
    background-color:#25383C;
}

#SideBar{
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#25383C;
    float:left;
    border:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

#MainBody{
    width:848px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#F88158;
    //background: url(Mainbodybg.png); 
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This does not look like a good use of tables `div>img+ul>li*6` plus some simple css

Comment: I am partidary of non use tables for this purposes, because it's not tabular data. It's better a div, the img float left and the right data will flown by default as you like. Simplest, cleanest, better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `vertical-align` attribute on the cell with the image. In this case, I believe you just want to add `vertical-align:bottom;` to get the data about the image to display aligned with the top of the image. Example here: http://jsbin.com/rofekasoto/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thnx for your help. Instead of using vertical-align: bottom  or top (working) i deleted the vertical-align: baseline; (line 24) from my css file. In case this action messes up something else i will put it back and use the way you said. Just saying in case it helps someone somehow. thnx again

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested table in the second column/cell:

```
<table style="width:50%" height = "350" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="1466570127.jpg" alt=""></img></td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>555 77 854</td></tr>
        <tr><td>555 77 855</td></tr>
        <tr><td>555 77 856</td></tr>
        <tr><td>555 77 857</td></tr>
        <tr><td>555 77 858</td></tr>
        <tr><td>555 77 859</td></tr>
      </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You've missed the `vertical-align` property or the `valign` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you add vertical align top to the css, it produces the result you are looking for.

```
th, td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```